# Unable to compile class for JSP: in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I am beginner in jsp.I did the simple program.but I got an error like **"Unable to compile class for JSP"**.I attached the code.can anyone solve this issue?Thanks in advance....

```html
JAVA CODE:

package com.vignesh.pac;

public class multiply {
 
 public static int doitwell(int n)
 {
  return n*n;
 }

}


JSP CODE:



<%@ page import="com.vignesh.pac.*" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>
PRODUCT
</title>
</head>
<body>

**<%= multiply.doitwell(12) %>**  //ERROR SHOWS IN THIS LINE

</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvfFh.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says it’s unable to find class multiply even though you’re doing a page import. That simply means your class is either not compiled, or not in the class path of the deployed web application.

Also, you may want to read about file and variable naming conventions in Java. See Hungarian notation and camel case directives.

Comment: what I have to change?

Comment: Make sure the folder containing the package for this class has been marked as a source folder, causing eclipse to add it to project build path. Then check your project deployment assembly and make sure compiled classes are being copied to WEB-INF/classes.